# Javascript for changing div height on button click?

Tags: javascript, html

> So  what my code looks like.. Now the problem is that Everything is fine when the result div opens, but when this page is accessed the main wrapper takes the height of the left nav.. 
>   I wanna know if there is a way i can modify the div height when the result div is called.. Is there a javascript to which an ajax call can be given?? 
>   Really appreciate the help.. Thanks!

```
<div id="main-container">

    <!--header starts-->
    <jsp:include page="../common/header.jsp" />
    <!--header ends-->

    <!--body content starts-->
    <div id="main-content-wrapper">

        <!--body content left starts-->
        <jsp:include page="../common/leftNavigation.jsp" />
        <!--body content left ends-->

        <!--body content right starts-->

        <form:form name="submitForm" action="storemonthly" method="POST"
            commandName="storePerformanceVO">

            <div id="printDiv">
                <div id="maincontent-right-wrapper">
                    <div class="page-heading-dailyroaster">
                        <spring:message
                            code="rmp.store_performance_monthly.page_header.store_performance_monthly" />
                    </div>
            <!--shop starts-->
                    <div class="store-setup-wrapper">

                        <!--shop starts-->
                        <div class="shop-promoter-wrapper">
                            <div class="shop-promoter-inner">

                                <ul>

                                    <li><spring:message
                                            code="rmp.store_performance_monthly.label.store" />:</li>
                                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                    <li><form:select path="storeid" style="width:200px;">
                                            <form:options items="${StoreList}" itemValue="storeId"
                                                itemLabel="storeName" />
                                        </form:select></li>
                                    <li><img src="../static/images/spacer.gif" width="26"
                                        height="1" /></li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!--shop ends-->



                    </div>
                    <!--shop ends-->

                    <!--daily-roaster-wrapper starts-->
                    <div id="resultDiv"></div>
                    <!--page bottom ends-->

                </div>

            </div>
        </form:form>
        <!--body content right ends-->


    </div>
    <!--body content ends-->
    <!--footer starts-->
    <div class="footer">&nbsp;</div>
    <!--footer ends-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the height of your result div

```
document.getElementById(DivID).style.height=50
```